# Creating a WebSocket Client for Mocha tests within a Sails.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, sails.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to use the socket.io-client in the Mocha tests of my Sails JS app to do calls like below. However the .get/.post do not get invoked and the test case times out.

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
io.sails.url = sails.getBaseUrl();

// This doesn't work
io.socket.get('/hello', function serverResponded (body, JWR) {
  console.log('Sails responded with: ', body);
  console.log('with headers: ', JWR.headers);
  console.log('and with status code: ', JWR.statusCode);
  io.socket.disconnect();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confusing `socket.io-client`, which is the low-level Socket.io client library, with `sails.io.js`, which is the Sails.js utility for communicating with a Sails app over sockets.  Take a look at the [`sails.io.js` README](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails.io.js) for instructions on how to use the Sails socket client from Node:

```
var socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client');
var sailsIOClient = require('sails.io.js');

// Instantiate the socket client (`io`)
// (for now, you must explicitly pass in the socket.io client when using this library from Node.js)
var io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);

// Set some options:
// (you have to specify the host and port of the Sails backend when using this library from Node.js)
io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
// ...

// Send a GET request to `http://localhost:1337/hello`:
io.socket.get('/hello', function serverResponded (body, JWR) {
  // body === JWR.body
  console.log('Sails responded with: ', body);
  console.log('with headers: ', JWR.headers);
  console.log('and with status code: ', JWR.statusCode);

  // ...
  // more stuff
  // ...


  // When you are finished with `io.socket`, or any other sockets you connect manually,
  // you should make sure and disconnect them, e.g.:
  io.socket.disconnect();

  // (note that there is no callback argument to the `.disconnect` method)
});
```